# Why girth of Petersen Graph is five? (Proof)

Tags: graph-theory

I want to know, what is the mathematical proof that shows the shortest cycle in Petersen Graph has length five?

Comment: What is your definition of the Petersen graph? It's pretty easy to prove if the Petersen graph is defined as the line graph of $K_5.$

Comment: There are three things to prove: (i) the graph contains a cycle of length five, (ii) it contains no triangle, and (iii) it contains no cycle of length four. Which parts (if any) have you done?

Comment: @bof, My definition of the Petersen graph is GP(5, 2) explained in this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PetersenGraph.html . We easily can see a cycle of length five. But I think we can use properties of Peterson Graph to prove that it contains no cycle of length four or three. I saw this proof later but at this time I can't remember it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peterson graph can be defined as follows:
It is a graph $G(V,E)$ in which V is the set of all 2-element subsets of $S = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and there is an edge $uv \in E$ if and only if $u$ and $v$ are disjoint.
Thus, there is no cycle of length 3, because it implies having at least 6 different elements in $S$.
Note that every 2 nonadjacent vertices have exactly one common neighbour (union of 2 nonadjacent vertices covers 3 elements of $S$, so there is only one 2-element subset adjacent to (or disjoint with) them.) If there is a cycle of length 4, then the 2 diagonal vertices (which are nonadjacent because there is no triangle) share two common neighbours which is not possible!
It is easy to see it has a cycle of length 5.

Answer (score 0):

One way to show that the Petersen Graph has no cycles of length $3$ is by examining its spectra. The eigenvalues of $\mathcal{P}$ are $3^{1}$, $(1)^{5}, (-2)^{4}$, where the exponents denote their multiplicities. Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{3}$ counts three times the number of triangles in a graph $G$ of order $n$. So we observe that $3^{3} + 5(1^{3}) + 4(-2)^{3} = 27 + 5 - 4(8) = 0$. So $\mathcal{P}$ has no three cycles.

To show that there is no four cycle, observe that every pair of non-adjacent vertices shares exactly one common neighbor. So now we select a vertex. Pick two of its neighbors to consider in a $4$-cycle. These two neighbors are not adjacent (we see this by inspection). In order for a $4$-cycle to exist, these two neighbors must share a second common vertex.

I will let you formalize the proof that no four-cycle exists. But that's the gist of what you want to show. Most of it you can see by inspection.