# prove that Petersen graph has no cycles less than or equal to 4

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonicity

I studying the proof that the Petersen graph is not Hamiltonian, and in the proof, they used an observation that seems intuitively correct but I want to provide rigorous proof for it, given that I'm taking an introductory course to discrete mathematics.

> **Claim: Petersen graph has no cycles less than or equal to 4**

I want to prove it by contradiction using the basics ideas, can you help me with that?

Comment: How you prove it will depend on how you defined the Petersen graph. Did you define it as the complement of the line graph of $K_5$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why girth of Petersen Graph is five? (Proof)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462092/why-girth-of-petersen-graph-is-five-proof). The first answer provides a proof by contradiction for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a simple argument by coloring the edges of the Petersen's graph as shown below:

[image]

First note that there are 3 types of edges:

- 5 blue edges forming outer cycle of length 5
- 5 pink edges forming inner cycle of length 5
- 5 green edges connecting outer nodes with inner nodes

Now, since there is a blue cycle of length 5 with 5 outer blue nodes, it makes it impossible to have a blue monochrome cycle of length $\leq 4$, because

- for creating a length-4 or length-3 cycle we must connect two non-adjacent blue nodes by an additional blue edge.
- in order to accommodate that additional blue edge, we must remove an exisiting blue edge from the blue cycle.
- but, minimum number of blue edges needed to construct a length-5 blue cycle with 5 blue nodes is 5, with each node having one incoming and one outgoing blue edge.
- hence, we can't remove an edge from the existing length-5 blue cycle, which contains 5 blue edges only.

Using same argument we can show that we can't have an inner monochrome pink cycle of length $\leq 4$.

Also, a cycle which is not monochromatic must have a green edge (connecting an inner and an outer node). Now, in order to have a non-monochrome cycle of length $\leq 4$, we must have

- either a couple of green edges from a pink node, which is impossible (since there is exactly one green edge incident on each pink node),
- or a couple of green edges incident on a blue node (again impossible),
- or it would need at least one additional blue edge (connecting two non-adjacent blue nodes) or one additional pink edge (connecting two non-adjacent pink nodes), making it impossible to have blue or pink cycles of length 5.

Comment: In summary, the above firstly proves cycles of length $\le 4$ are impossible for only blue or pink nodes because cycle-5 can't have one smaller cycle inside it. Then we must have one green edge which already has nodes, then for the cycle-3 either one pink edge or one blue is added but then we can't proceed to form one cycle. For cycle-4, similarly 2 blue edges, 1 blue 1 green, 1 pink 1 green or 2 pink. But all of them can't form one cycle.